# Three.js draggable cube

Tags: javascript, three.js

Attending to this tutorial [Draggable cubes](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) I tried to move my personal geometry cube but doesn't work. In the code below it works with geometry2 but doesn't work with geometry0, maybe there is some setting in geometry0 that doesn't permit movement?

```
//geometry0 doesn't move
geometry0 = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry0.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5), new     THREE.Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5,    0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5,   0.5, -0.5)]; 
geometry0.faces = [new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 1), new THREE.Face3(3, 1, 0), new THREE.Face3(4, 5, 6),   new THREE.Face3(4, 6, 7), new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 5), new THREE.Face3(0, 5, 4), new THREE.Face3(1, 2,   6), new THREE.Face3(1, 6, 5), new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 7), new THREE.Face3(2, 7, 6), new THREE.Face3(3,  0, 4), new THREE.Face3(3, 4, 7)]; 
geometry0.computeFaceNormals();
geometry0.computeVertexNormals();
var material0 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x39d2dbe7fff39d2, transparent: true,   opacity: 0 });
mesh0 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry0, material0);
egh0 = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh0, 0x000 );
egh0.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( egh0 );




geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry() // it works
geometry2.vertices = [new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.166667, 0.5),  new THREE.Vector3(0, -0.5, 0.5), new THREE.Vector3(0.5, -0.5, 0.5)]; 
geometry2.faces = [new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2), new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 1), new THREE.Face3(1, 3, 2),  new THREE.Face3(2, 3, 0)]; 
geometry2.computeFaceNormals();
geometry2.computeVertexNormals();
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 });
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2);
scene.add(mesh2);
egh2 = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh2, 0x000 );
egh2.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add( egh2 );







geometryContainer.push(mesh0);
geometryContainer.push(mesh2);

 plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000, 8, 8 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00, opacity: 0.25 } ) );
            //plane.visible = false;
            scene.add( plane );


function render() 
{
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
renderer.clearDepth();
renderer.render( scene_text, camera );
}


        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            mouse2D.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
            mouse2D.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;



            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2D.x, mouse2D.y, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );


              if ( SELECTED ) {
               console.log("selected");
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );
                                   console.log(intersects[ 0 ]);
                SELECTED.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point.sub( offset ) );
                                    console.log(SELECTED.position);
                                    render();
                return;

            }


            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( geometryContainer );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
         console.log(intersects);
                if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                    INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();

                    plane.position.copy( INTERSECTED.position );

                    plane.lookAt( camera.position );
             render();
                }

                container.style.cursor = 'pointer';

            } else {

                if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );

                INTERSECTED = null;

                container.style.cursor = 'auto';

            }

        }




                    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse2D.x, mouse2D.y, 0.5 );
            projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( geometryContainer );
            console.log(intersects);
            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                //controls.enabled = false;
              controls.noRotate=true;
                SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );
                offset.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point ).sub( plane.position );

                container.style.cursor = 'move';

            }

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();
         controls.noRotate=false;
            //controls.enabled = true;

            if ( INTERSECTED ) {

                plane.position.copy( INTERSECTED.position );

                SELECTED = null;

            }

            container.style.cursor = 'auto';

        }
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters but geometry0 is transparent with 0 opacity. Also its color is very strange. I am surprised you can see something.

Comment: @gaitat do you think issue can dipend by geometry0?

Comment: Yes I think it might.